# How to extract all text between two tags including the tags but not the whole line

Tags: bash, unix

I'm a newbie to unix. I want to extract all the text between two keywords including those keywords but not any other text in the output even if the texts fall in the same line of the keywords.

Below is the sample file: test.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <spml:batchResponse executionTime="6066" result="success" xmlns:spml="urn:si:names:prov:gw:SPML:2:0" xmlns:customer="urn:si:names:prov:gw:HOME:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><version>v10</version><response executionTime="45" result="success" xsi:type="spml:ModifyResponse" requestID="41f01d9f:1616237351f:-761e" timestamp="2018/02/05 12:40:57,767 +0600">
  <version>v10</version>
  <objectclass>customer</objectclass>
  <identifier alias="method">1234</identifier>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="source/testInject" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:METHODNAME">
  <methodInfo>FIRE</methodInfo>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="node" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:NODE">
  <iserv>200</iserv>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  </response><response executionTime="95" result="success" xsi:type="spml:ModifyResponse" requestID="41f01d9f:1616237351f:-7696" timestamp="2018/02/05 12:42:57,767 +0600">
  <version>v10</version>
  <objectclass>customer</objectclass>
  <identifier alias="method">4321</identifier>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="source/testInject" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:METHODNAME">
  <methodInfo>FIRE</methodInfo>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="node" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:NODE">
  <iserv>200</iserv>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  </response><response executionTime="65" result="success" xsi:type="spml:ModifyResponse" requestID="41f01d9f:16162373512:-9621" timestamp="2018/02/05 12:39:20,767 +0600">
  <version>v10</version>
  <objectclass>customer</objectclass>
  <identifier alias="method">3214</identifier>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="source/testInject" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:METHODNAME">
  <methodInfo>FIRE</methodInfo>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="node" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:NODE">
  <iserv>200</iserv>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  </response></spml:batchResponse>
```

Below is my expected output, where I want to extract all the texts between

```
  <response executionTime="45" result="success" xsi:type="spml:ModifyResponse" requestID="41f01d9f:1616237351f:-761e" timestamp="2018/02/05 12:40:57,767 +0600">
  <version>v10</version>
  <objectclass>customer</objectclass>
  <identifier alias="method">1234</identifier>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="source/testInject" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:METHODNAME">
  <methodInfo>FIRE</methodInfo>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="node" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:NODE">
  <iserv>200</iserv>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  </response>
  <response executionTime="95" result="success" xsi:type="spml:ModifyResponse" requestID="41f01d9f:1616237351f:-7696" timestamp="2018/02/05 12:42:57,767 +0600">
  <version>v10</version>
  <objectclass>customer</objectclass>
  <identifier alias="method">4321</identifier>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="source/testInject" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:METHODNAME">
  <methodInfo>FIRE</methodInfo>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="node" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:NODE">
  <iserv>200</iserv>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  </response>
  <response executionTime="65" result="success" xsi:type="spml:ModifyResponse" requestID="41f01d9f:16162373512:-9621" timestamp="2018/02/05 12:39:20,767 +0600">
  <version>v10</version>
  <objectclass>customer</objectclass>
  <identifier alias="method">3214</identifier>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="source/testInject" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:METHODNAME">
  <methodInfo>FIRE</methodInfo>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  <modification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" scope="uniqueTypeMapping" name="node" operation="modify">
  <valueObject xmlns:ns2="urn:si:names:prov:gw:customer:1:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:NODE">
  <iserv>200</iserv>
  </valueObject>
  </modification>
  </response>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: For parsing XML consider XML-specific tools such as `xmlstarlet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `xmlstarlet` tool (if it's not installed)

Run command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//response' -n input.xml
```

---

Or the same with `xmllint` tool:

```
xmllint --xpath '//response' input.xml
```

Comment: can the same output be achieved by xmllint..?